# ActiveAdmin I18n.locale changed automatically on test development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-i18n

I going to uncomment before action on `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
# config.before_action :do_something_awesome
```

But when I activate this default comment out, test failed for I18n.locale changing.
I'm using `:ja` but it looks change to `en`

**config/application.rb**

```rb
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
```

test failed like this.
`"XXX"=>"translation missing: en.xxx.yyy"`

development environment looks like is not affected.

I don't understand why even if just uncomment below line.

```rb
config.before_action :do_something_awesome
```

Please help me if you know anything that cloud help me.

---

Environment Information
Rails 5.2.0
ActiveAdmin 1.3.0